# Access 2010 DB Exploding in Size

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have an Access database that I created from an Excel spreadsheet.

The DB contains a main table with 58 fields, three other tables that have about 10 fields, and a last table with two fields. Most of the new information is going into the main table.

After a days use (two users), the database is exploding from 20MB to 50MB. Some new records are being added, but not enough to generate 30MB. My main table had 4000 records after I finished my import from Excel and compacted the database.

The users have not added more than a few dozen new records and the database drops back down to around 20MB after a compact. Is this something that is common in 2010? Never experienced this with 2000/2003.

Thanks,
Westley

Comment: Is there a lot of editing/deleting of rows

Comment: Terrible advice @Aaron Kempf: the last thing you want to be doing with SQL Server is auto shrinking a database!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is common.

> The most common causes of Access
>   database bloat are over-use of
>   temporary tables and over-use of
>   non-querydef SQL. Whenever you code an
>   SQL string outside of a querydef,
>   Access must "bind" that statement
>   EVERY time it is run. This process
>   takes a small amount of time and uses
>   a large amount of workspace that is
>   not recovered until you compact the
>   db. Querydef's are "bound" when they
>   are saved and when the db is
>   compacted. [Ref](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=48759).

Lots of insertions/deletes will also cause growth.

[ACC: Database Grows Rapidly When You Modify SQL Statements](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165823)

Of interest?: [Growing MS Access File Size problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450995/growing-ms-access-file-size-problem)

Answer (score 0):

**Pictures in reports can also cause the database to grow in size**
I have found another way that an access database can increase in size.   If you have a report (and possibly also a form?) where there are pictures that are inserted from an external file then one of the "picture type" options is 'shared'.  If this option is used then Access stores a new local copy of the picture every time a different picture is used.  My 1MByte Access database ended up with 500MByte of internally stored pictures.  There does not appear to be any way of flushing them and compacting the database does not clear them.
**The solution is to use the 'linked' "picture type" setting**.  I copied the database contents to a new database, and it has stayed at 1MByte.