# MS Access database size growing

Tags: excel, ms-access

We use a MS Access database which has a linked Excel table. This Excel linked to a SQL database report. From this Excel file we load the data to an internal table of the Access database. The loading process is the following:

1. run a delete query (this delete all data from internal table)
2. run an append query which loads the data from excel to the emptied internal table

These two steps cause the file size to grow (~1150 kb/running) even though the amount of data does not change after loading!

Because of this, we need to compact and repair the database frequently.

How can I stop this growth?

Comment: AFAIK Access has a pathological habit of creating (and not deleting) temporary objects for many operations, including selection queries (the most brutal file increase I've seen is when running a crosstab query). Unfortunately, I don't know if this can be prevented.

Comment: Maybe [this question and its answers can be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450995/growing-ms-access-file-size-problem)

Comment: So your data goes SQL > Excel > MS Access? That seems like a step backward to me!

Answer (score 2):

Don't import the file.

You have it already linked, so create a simple select query with the linked file as the only source source, and use this to filter and convert (for example text dates to true Date values) the data and create the expressions you may need to proceed.

Then use this query as source for your further processing.

If this is not possible, (re)create a temporary database from scratch, fill a table in this, and link this to your main database.

That said, any Access database will grow when used if it is not write protected. This normally causes no harm.